# Múltiplos contextos Migrations Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, migrations

Tenho vários projetos e cada projeto possui um contexto.
Gostaria de saber, como utilizar o *Migrations* para atualizar e gerar apenas um banco de dados desses vários contextos?

Comment: você já leu este artigo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx ? Neste artigo ele menciona uma configuração nova do EF6 que permite isto, `ContextKey`,

Comment: Sim, mas ele nao especifica sobre os varios projetos e contextos.

Comment: E as entidades dos Projetos se comunicam entre si

Comment: Veja se essa thred o ajuda, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10009491/2187618.

Comment: faz um tempo já... conseguiu resolver? entendi que cada projeto tem um contexto, mas a estrutura do banco é a mesma usada por todos eles?

Comment: Até onde sei para gerar um único banco todos os contextos devem apontar para o mesmo caminho para poder unificar todas as entidades

Answer (score 1):

Múltiplos contextos são úteis para estruturar/isolar áreas do projeto; obviamente isso aumenta a complexidade. Então você pode criar cada contexto apontando para a mesma base e realizar o trabalho normalmente.

Answer (score -1):

Um diferencial do EF6 é que ele foi lançado com a funcionalidade para suportar [multiplos contextos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574253.aspx). Encontrei algumas respostas para o seu problema :

**Tutorial :**

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html

**Resposta :**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537558/multiple-db-contexts-in-the-same-db-and-application-in-ef-6-and-code-first-migra

Answer (score -2):

Você de criar apenas UMA conexão, e utiliza ele para os seus projeto. Assim:

```
Context contexto = new Context();   <----(cria uma conexao)

ProjetoRepository nomeRepositorio = new ProjetoRepository (contexto);
(ProjetoRepository usando a conexao "contexto ")

OutroProjetoRepository nomeOutroReposito = new OutroProjetoRepository (contexto);
(OutroProjetoRepository usando a mesma conexao "contexto ")
```

Answer (score -4):

Como cada contexto é uma instância completamente diferente acredito que isto não seja possível.
A não ser que você crie um contexto que gerencie todos os contextos e englobe em um só.

Comment: Se você acha que não é possível, demonstre o porque. Se acha que é criando um contexto que gerencie os outros, demonstre o que fazer.